# Can we apply to the Marie Curie postdoc fellowship with two supervisors at two different universities?

Tags: postdocs, marie-curie

I'm thinking of applying to the Marie Curie postdoc fellowship.
My topic is a interdiscipline, two professors from two universities both participate in.
One of them can be the supervisor from the host organization, but can the other professor also involved in the the application?

Anyone tried to apply the fellowship with two supervisors before?

Comment: Have you tried reading the provided documentation?

Answer (score -1):

There's also a less known Global Postdoc fellowship that is made for this purpose: https://marie-sklodowska-curie-actions.ec.europa.eu/actions/postdoctoral-fellowships. Conditions apply (see below).

*Global Postdoctoral Fellowships. They fund the mobility of researchers outside Europe. The fellowship lasts between 2 to 3 years, of which the first 1 to 2 years will be spent in a non-associated Third Country, followed by a mandatory return phase of 1 year to an organisation based in an EU Member State or Horizon Europe Associated Country. Only nationals or long-term residents of the EU Member States or Horizon Europe Associated Countries can apply.*

I don't know if this applies to you, though.

P.S. There must be, in any case, only one main PI or supervisor for bureaucratic reasons. This was some time ago for me, but it was not possible to have them both with equal role.